# Live Agent, "Skills" edit page showing a text box with label "Developer Name". What does Developer means here?

Tags: liveagent

In Live Agent, "Skills" edit page there is a text box with label "Developer Name". What does Developer means here? Is this related to "software developer" or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few areas of Salesforce that Developer Name and Name are used. By having two different fields, you can have a developer name field that doesn't change and can more reliably be used in code. That allows the Name field to be modified and be used more of as a label. You can think of the two as Name be the the Label and Developer Name be the API Name.

Another object that uses this is Record Type.

Comment: might be i framed the question differently. I meant in what way "Developer Name" means to Skills in context?

Comment: Developer Name is just the developer friendly name for the skill that you can use to query skills. It shouldn't change, but you can can change the Name field so it displays differently throughout Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

The developer name for a skill is the equivalent of the API name for a field. This is the name  you will use if you were to query or use this component via the API.